# Run packages from Workstation?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, workstation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are using TurtleBot. There is a laptop directly connected to the TurtleBot. In addition, there is a workstation which connects to the laptop through wireless connection.

According to my understanding, some packages (e.g. teleop) are run from the laptop, while some can be run from the workstation (e.g. rviz). Since we have a powerful workstation, it makes sense to run heavy packages (e.g. opencv, navigation) from the workstation. However, it seems that opencv, amcl, move_base, etc. are now run from the laptop (or am I wrong?)

Hence, my question is, is it possible to run these packages from the workstation? Thank you very much indeed for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59844/run-packages-from-workstation-???/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is. Presuming [your network is set up correctly](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup), you just need to launch the appropriate file (`roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch`, for example) on your workstation instead of the laptop. One thing you should be mindful of is the bandwidth requirements. Specifically, if the packages you're running on the workstation rely on point cloud data instead of simple images or the LaserScan generated by the [pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan) node, you'll run into issues.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1